# Which site gives accurate result for mobile site

Tags: mobile

I have found a couple of sites where I can test my responsive site. I have seen most of them are for the iPhone but every site gives different views of the structure of the website. Is there any particular site where I can able to test my site?

Answer (score 0):

A caveat first (it might be obvious), all of these "preview" sites are just glorified iframes set at certain widths. Unless you have very simple media queries, it may not be an accurate representation of viewing the site on the specified device. For example, if you've accounted for pixel density or pixel ratio in your media queries, that and other properties may be ignored.

The only accurate way to preview your site is through a simulator (which still can be dubious), or on the actual target device.

Answer (score 0):

To test a website is responsive, i found some tools website where it works like live.

http://ami.responsivedesign.is/

Example: http://192.168.10.151/test

even local server ip address also works on here, when anybody develop a site inside his local server.

For different kind of device testing may be this site will be very helpful.

http://responsivetesttool.com/

here you can test using mobile/tab/device model.